# Algoritmo para conectar pontos num gráfico com linhas curvas

Tags: algoritmo, matemática, gráfico

Preciso desenvolver um algoritmo que conecta pontos de uma forma **não linear**, ou seja, com curvas suaves, como na imagem abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O problema é que não encontro a melhor solução, seja usando [Curvas Bezier](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curva_de_B%C3%A9zier), [Interpolação Polimonial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_interpolation), [Ajuste de Curvas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curve_fitting), entre outros.

Resumindo, preciso de uma fórmula que interpole os pontos conforme a figura acima, gerando N pontos intermediários entre uma coordenada e outra.

Ex: Na imagem acima, a primeira coordenada (c1) é (x=1, y=220) e a segunda (c2) é (x=2, y=40).

Então se eu quiser criar por exemplo 4 coordenadas intermediárias entre c1 e c2 eu terei que obter um array (x, y) de 4 elementos mais ou menos assim:

```
[1.2, 180], [1.4, 140], [1.6, 120], [1.8, 80]
```

Alguém teria alguma ideia?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hermite_interpolation

Comment: @Victor Stafusa, obrigado, mas acho que eu estou alguns passos atrás de seu conhecimento. Não sou um matemático e não tenho muita intimidade com fórmulas avançadas. Fica mais fácil para minha compreensão ver um código de qualquer linguagem em funcionamento para entender o "passo a passo". Você poderia me ajudar nisso?

Comment: Por exemplo, como no exemplo que coloquei acima, entre os dois primeiros pontos conhecidos (x = 1 e x = 2), como eu calcularia y quando x for = 1.2, 1.4 e assim por diante?

Comment: Também não sou matemático e não sei como resolver isso sem que tenha que dedicar ao menos algumas horas nessa tarefa. Só estou te apontando o caminho, que uma possível solução seria usar essa interpolação Hermite. O princípio é que se você tem n pontos pré-definidos, então existe alguma função polinomial de grau n-1 que passa por esses pontos, e essa interpolação de Hermite é usada para determinar que função polinomial é essa. No entanto, ao menos ainda, não tenho conhecimento suficiente para entender com profundidade como funciona essa interpolação.

Comment: Encontrei a resposta para esta pergunta no stackoverflow em inglês:
https://stackoverflow.com/q/51690981/5074998

Answer (score 0):

O que você quer é uma interpolação dos pontos.

Isso consiste em encontrar uma função f(x) que dado n pontos p1,p2,...,pn, f(x) passe por todos os pontos.

Como isso é feito?

Vamos pensar no caso mais simples, 2 pontos (n=2), nesse caso, queremos encontrar uma reta (lembre, sempre há uma reta que passa por 2 pontos não-coincidentes), uma reta é uma função da forma

f(x) = ax + b

Note que f(x) é um polinômio de grau 1, no caso da interpolação polinomial, queremos que f(x) seja um polinômio de menor grau possível.

Existem diversos algoritmos de interpolação, você pode encontrar a descrição deles aqui, mas a maioria das linguagens já tem uma lib com isso implementado

https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polin%C3%B3mio_de_Newton

[https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polinômio_de_Lagrange](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polin%C3%B4mio_de_Lagrange)

Comment: Obrigado, já consegui desenvolver um algoritmo com Interpolação Polinomial Bicúbica.